# Why the source address comes before destination address in IP Header?

Tags: networking, ip, protocols

Why the source address comes before destination address in IP Header? Is there any specific reason for this? Contrary to this in Ethernet header Destination MAC comes before Source MAC.

Comment: You should ask this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet and IP were created by different people, and they are maintained by different standards bodies. While both were created around the same time, it wasn't clear that either or both would become dominant.

Ethernet was created by Bob Metcalfe, et al, for LANs. IP was created by Vint Cerf, et al, for connecting disparate sites (WAN). Over the years, the market settled primarily on those two technologies as the dominant ones, but it took a couple of decades for that to happen.

For the particular reasons why the contents or order of the IP header was chosen, you can read interviews with Vint Cerf, or you could send an e-mail and ask him yourself.

Comment: Hi Ron. I posted question to Vint Cerf. He told it's PURELY ARBITRARY. :-) Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That is often the answer to questions about the design of IP.